# SimpleDateFormat not properly handling 12 a.m

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse the string `"2/20/2012 12:00:00 AM"` using `SimpleDateFormat`, and it seems to be coming out 12 p.m. instead.

```
    Date fromFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa")
                       .parse("2/20/2012 12:00:00 AM");

    // Calendar months are 0-indexed
    Date fromCal = new Date(new GregorianCalendar(2012, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0)
                       .getTimeInMillis());

    System.out.println(fromFmt);
    System.out.println(fromCal);
```

outputs:

```
Mon Feb 20 12:00:00 PST 2012
Mon Feb 20 00:00:00 PST 2012
```

I would expect both of them to output the latter. Is there something wrong with my format string?

(And please nobody say 'use JodaTime'.)

Comment: The `HH` is 24 hour clock so you are providing an invalid time. try `hh` instead.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")
```

Notice I'm using `hh` instead of `HH`.  The former does this:

> Hour in am/pm (1-12)

`HH` does this:

> Hour in day (0-23)

---

You're telling the `SimpleDateFormat` that you're going to pass in an hour in the 0-23 range, but you're not actually doing that.  That's why you get this issue.